# How to append an associative array to the end of another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on my cart for a project and having issue. I have really tried to sort it out myself but same issue. 
Basically people will select shoes size from a dropdown menu to be sent to the cart. and the code will check :

- -if there is already value in the session cart : if same value for id and size, then we increase the qty of the existing value
- -if there is already value in the session cart : if the id value is same, but the size value different, then it is a new value, append to
  the existing value.

  For the first check the code work fine, it checks the existing values in the session cart and if it is the same id and same size, the qty increase fine.

  the issue is in the second check: when i select another size in the dropdown but with the same item id, the new value (id and size) just erase the existing values in cart.

**What i want is that: if item id is same, but has a different size, then it is a new value and that array value need to be appended to end of the session cart as a new value**

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $items = array(
  array('id' => '1', 'desc' => 'sneaker','price' => 24.95, 'size'=>'424546'),
  array('id' => '2', 'desc' => 'Reebok','price' => 200, 'size'=>'323845'),
  array('id' => '3', 'desc' => 'Songs of the Goldfish (2CD set)','price' => 19.99),
  array('id' => '4', 'desc' => 'Simply JavaScript (SitePoint)', 'price' => 39.95)
  );

session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
 $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
 }

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Buy')  {
 $size="";
 //Get the values for the post and make sure they are integers
 $pid = filter_var( $_POST['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range'=> 1) );
 $size = $_POST['doSize'];
 if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$pid])) {

    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key) {

if ($key['id'] === $pid and $key['size'] !== $size) {
        echo "NOT SAME SIZE";
        $si = $size;
$_SESSION['cart'][$key['id']] = array('id'=>$pid, 'size'=>$si, 'quantity'=>1);  

      }

      elseif ( $key['id'] === $pid and $key['size']=== $size ) {
         $_SESSION['cart'][$key['id']]['quantity']++;
            echo "YES CORRECT";
      } 
   }//end foreach
   print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
 }//end isset session cart

 else{
$_SESSION['cart'][$pid]= array('id'=>$pid, 'size'=>$size, 'quantity'=>1);

 foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key) {
      echo $key['id'];
    }

print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
   }
 }//END POST 
include'cat.html';

//unset($_SESSION['cart']);
 ?>
```

Here the cart.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  <title>Product catalog</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type"
  content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <style type="text/css">
 table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 td, th {
 border: 1px solid black;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
<body>
 <p>Your cart contains <?php echo count($_SESSION['cart']);?> item(s).</p>
 <p><a href="?cart">View your cart</a></p>
 <table border="1">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Item Description</th>
 <th>Price</th>
 <th>Size</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>

<tbody>
 <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $item['desc']; ?></td>
 <td>
 $<?php echo number_format($item['price'], 2); ?>
 </td>
 <td>

<form action="" method="post">

 <?php if (isset($item['size'])) { ?>

 <select name="doSize">
 <?php foreach(str_split($item['size'], 2) as $size):?>
 <option value="<?php echo $size;?>"><?php echo $size;?></option>
 <?php endforeach;?>


 </select>
 <?php }?>
  </td>

 <td>
 <div>
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>"/>
 <input type="submit" name="action" value="Buy"/>
 </div>
 </form>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <p>All prices are in imaginary dollars.</p>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: What's your question or problem?

Comment: I see this error all the time. When you loop through the cart array, just because the current item doesn't match the user's selection, it doesn't mean it wasn't found, because the item could be in a different array element. Why is this such a hard concept for beginning programmers to get? You have to wait until you get through the whole array before you can know if it was found or not.

Comment: @Barmar: Ok, but i used a condition comparison to make sure the values are there? is not correct the way i did?

Comment: @DossSmart No, it's wrong. You're already doing something before all items are evaluated. You have to do something after all items have been evaluated and determined if you need to add something or update the quantity (ok, this can be done in the loop and then break it).

Comment: Why did you undo my cleanup of your code indentation?

Comment: @Barmar i do not cleanup anything

Comment: Look at my edit #3, I fixed up the indentation of your PHP. Then you made edit #4, and you put back your original PHP with bad indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop is wrong. When you see a cart entry with a different ID or size from the one the user selected, it doesn't mean it's not found, because it could be in a different element of the array. You need to wait until you get to the end of the loop to know whether the item was found.

```
$found = false;
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as &$key) {
    // Use &$key reference so we can modify the element
    if ( $key['id'] === $pid and $key['size']=== $size ) {
        $key['quantity']++;
        echo "YES CORRECT";
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}//end foreach
if (!$found) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = array('id' => $pid, 'size' => $size, 'quantity' => 1);
}
```

Also, you can't use `$pid` as the key of `$_SESSION['cart']`, since you can have different sizes with the same `$pid`, and an associative array can't have multiple elements with the same key.

Comment: i have tested your code..but there is still an issue, when the same id and the size are already in the cart; the quantity need to increment by...but the code does not do that part.

Comment: It should. That's what `$key['quantity']++;` does. Did you remember to change `as $key` to `as &$key` as I explain in the comment?

Comment: YES it does work..thank you so much....but please i need to know what is this technique - &$key - you use. I want to make research on  it.

Comment: It's called a variable reference, it's explained in the PHP manual.

Answer (score -2):

$example_parent_array = array('example_1', 'example_2');

$example_parent_array['example_1'] = array('child_array_index' => "Example");

echo $example_parent_array['example_1']['child_array_index']; // Outputs: "Example"

Comment: Huh? What is this?